# Charging a capacitor using a capacitor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capacitance, home-experiment

I recently did an experiment using a fully charged capacitor (assumed) and charged a separate capacitor through fixed resistor. We measured the potential difference of the capacitor being charged. We produced a graph of the potential difference against time. I expected the the graph to follow a normal charging graph with a gradient similar to a logarithmic graph which is true however the gradient of the graph at the end will become negative which suggested there is potential difference lost in the capacitor. Is there any reasons for this?

I cant show the circuit but it is similar to a charging circuit but the cell is replaced with a fully charged capacitor.

Comment: You can combine both capacitors into one equivalent capacitor, which means that the circuit (neglecting non-ideal behavior of either capacitor) behaves exactly like a simple RC discharge circuit.

Comment: Sorry I may not have describe the experiment that well. However, the graph is not one of a discharge circuit. Since it is charging, it produces a graph similar to a charging graph however the graph will bend towards the x axis at the end.

Comment: One capacitor is discharging, the other one is charging, until both capacitors have exactly the same potential difference. Isn't that the circuit you are describing? If not, I am visualizing the wrong circuit. Can you point to a circuit diagram or post a drawing?

Comment: I should have mentioned this but the circuit is not connected to a power source. So it is just capacitors and resistance ( with a voltmeter in the circuit).

Comment: What do you mean by the gradient of the graph becoming negative?  Do you mean that the voltage on the  initially-uncharged cap starts at zero, increases (exponentially, not logarithmically) and then at some point reverses direction and decreases?  If so, by how much?  1% of maximum value?  10%? 20%?

Comment: Post the graph! But I suspect your system was undergoing heavily damped oscillations - the small inductance of the connecting wire turned it into a very poor LC circuit.

Comment: @garyp I mean that the graph peaks but then it drops

Answer (score 4):

Comment on the question (v1): If you're confused by long-time behavior of your circuit, its behavior may be sensitive to details which are safe to neglect when describing short-time behavior. If you want a real answer, you should edit your question to include a *complete* circuit diagram, and perhaps a plot of your data.

For example: in one of my labs I have students charge a 200 µF capacitor through a 500 kΩ resistor, which has a time constant of 100 seconds.
However, the voltmeter they use to monitor the capacitor has an input resistance of 10 MΩ.
Students (and sometimes faculty, ahem) who disconnect the power supply while the capacitor is charged and monitor the "unconnected" voltage on the capacitor are surprised to see the charge on the capacitor trickle away; it trickles away through the voltmeter, with a time constant $\rm 10\,M\Omega \cdot 200\,\mu{}F \approx 30\,minutes$.

Comment: how come it trickles away?

Comment: This may indeed be the right answer, and I think it likely that it is.  There are other conducting paths for current, for example a light coating of oil on insulated wire.  And there are others.  The circuit will also have stray inductances, as mentioned in a comment.  The key is the first sentence of this answer.  How much time elapses after closing the switch before you notice the decline?

Comment: Also, all capacitors leak.  The amount of leakage depends on the quality of manufacturing.  If this is a student lab, there's a good chance that they are cheap capacitors. If it's one of those 1 F capacitors, I'd consider the possibility of leakage.  I personally don't trust them, but I have no real reason for my distrust.

Comment: i didnt close the switch, sorry i cant show the diagram neither can i show the graph at this time. But the graph will hit a peak voltage and then gradually drop.

Comment: @ObnoxiousFrog Are you measuring the voltage drop across the capacitor by occasionally touching the capacitor with a voltmeter? Or by leaving a voltmeter in parallel with the capacitor and occasionally looking at it?

Comment: Hi, I just started learning about charging capacitor. I learned that that for a capacitor consisting of two parallel plates, there exist a variable Q, which is the amount of charge the capacitor can hold. Is the charge evenly distributed over the two plates? And if that is the case, how do electrons flow onto the two plates in a current where electrons flow in only one way? If all there is, is air between the two plates, electrons can never come back to the battery.

Comment: @user132522 Welcome to Physics.SE! It sounds like you should [ask a new question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

In the real world you can never rid yourself of resistance in an electrical circuit. There is resistance in the connecting wires and resistance internal to the capacitor itself. So once you close the circuit and current starts moving, some of that electrical energy will be lost to heat, dissipated by resistance.

Comment: Energy lost to heat while the voltages of the two caps equalize does not explain why the voltage of _both_ caps would decrease after their voltages have become practically equal.  Leakage (through surface contamination, through internal mechanisms, and through the voltmeter itself _might_ be the explanation.)

Comment: @jameslarge Any element in the circuit path that conducts will be subject to $I^2*R$ loss including my examples and the examples you posed. The voltage you begin with in one capacitor represents the total (potential) energy. Without losses, the connection of the two capacitors should result in roughly half the voltage you started with across each at steady state, right? When there is a loss of energy it will lead to lower but equal voltages at steady state than half the voltage you started with.

Comment: What you say is true, the total energy stored in the capacitors at the end of the experiment will be less than at the start; but that answers a different question from the one that the OP asked.  The question was, Why did the circuit fail to reach an equilibrium in which both capacitors held a constant charge and no current flowed?